# Create Variation with colo

Tags: excel

I have a excel file that I need to create variation. Example I have shoe that have a size in col A and a second attribute in Col B color

I would like to have the first attibute size to have each color related to the size exemple
Size-Color

8 Blue

8 Green

8 Red

9 Blue

9 Green

9 Red

...etc

Hope I am clear, this is for a excel file that i will be importing in our wordpress woocommerce product variation import.

Answer (score 0):

For e.g. cell D2, put this conditional formatting formula in it

`=E2="Blue"`

and you can set the format to blue, obviously.

You'll need the same formula for each colour, then just floodfill all the cells you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think my question is not clear.

2 attributs, Color and Size each has there value. I want to something that will create the variation for me Color 1-Size 1, Color 1-Size 2, Color 1-Size 3, etc...

You can look the file I have. Right now i have to copy the line with the color ROUGE (red) 5 time and then change the value of the size.

So i am looking for something i will put my attribut 1 in a col, in col b all the variation for it and it will create the variation

http://screencast.com/t/dANPyK1uiQ

regards